# How do I define a set in typescript?

Tags: typescript

The typescript [basic types documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html) describes using Arrays as a primitive type

The relative syntax I would like is

```
const numbers: string[] = []
```

How do I do the same thing with a set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling new Set with the angle brackets type assertion

```
const issuersSet = new Set<string>();
```